# Use Microsoft Edge browser with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, microsoft-edge

How do you configure VS2013 to use the Edge browser on Windows 10? It currently says "Pick Application" in the run button which then launches IE11.

I'd have thought finding the executable would be an option but that doesn't appear that easy with Edge. If one looks at the properties of Edge when running, it's called "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe" - that doesn't look that permanent to me.

Comment: On Windows 10, it appears by default on top of the list. Did you try with Visual Studio 2015, to check if the problem persists?

Answer (score 3):

You will need the Windows 10 SDK and ideally Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Hmm, not quite ready to jump to VS2015 but will give the SDK a go

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [MicrosoftEdgeLauncher](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdgeLauncher#visual-studio-launching-microsoft-edge), an open source project we've made public specifically for this kind of scenario.

Comment: This thing works perfectly! Just download the latest "MicrosoftEdgeLauncher" from Antón Molleda's link. Then click on the expander next to the browse button, choose "Browse With..." and find  "MicrosoftEdgeLauncher.exe" in your download folder.